# Office.js: ItemNotFound: The requested resource doesn't exist

Tags: office-js, excel-2016

I'm creating an Office Add-in that runs in a task pane which is launched by clicking a button from the command ribbon. The app itself is a simple lookup tool. You select a cell (or range of cells) and it hits another endpoint (one I've setup) to lookup and return related information.

**On most spreadsheets, everything works as expected, however on some spreadsheets, it seems to break trying to hit the endpoint, and I get this error:**

```
ItemNotFound: The requested resource doesn't exist.
```

However, I know **the resource does exist and that it is working properly** because I can copy the data over to another sheet within the same file and the add-in works fine; however, I can't seem to get it working on this particular main sheet.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you provide the code that is triggering the error condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I was mistaken, my endpoint was not related to this issue.**

Turns out I was having issues with [Worksheet -> getRange()](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/master/reference/excel/worksheet.md#getrangeaddress-string) as a result of having spaces in the sheet name and probably using it incorrectly.

Here's an example. **This type of code worked for me just fine** if there were no spaces in the sheet name:

```
      Excel.run(async (ctx) => {
          var sheetName = 'Sheet1';
          var rangeAddress = 'A1:A4';
          var address = sheetName +"!"+ rangeAddress;
          var worksheet = ctx.workbook.worksheets.getItem(sheetName);
          var range = worksheet.getRange(address);
          await ctx.sync();
          ...
```

However, if I tried to use the same code, on a sheet name that had spaces, everything would blow up:

```
    var sheetName = 'Sheet Two';
```

**What worked for me** (Just pass the "range" part to the getRange() function, not my whole address):

```
      Excel.run(async (ctx) => {
          var sheetName = 'Sheet1';
          var rangeAddress = 'A1:A4';
          var worksheet = ctx.workbook.worksheets.getItem(sheetName);
          var range = worksheet.getRange(rangeAddress);
          await ctx.sync();
          ...
```

Answer (score 1):

This is likely an error with the add-in and not with your external resource.  Excel will throw `ItemNotFound: The requested resource doesn't exist.` when you try to use range.getUsedRange() and there is nothing in the range.

If you log the error with OfficeHelpers.Utilities.log() (found [here](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-helpers)), it will provide you the context you need to see why it threw that error.

Comment: Awesome, I did not know about OfficeHelpers.Utilities.log(). Will def look into that, thanks.

Comment: the question is also, how to test if the range has or has not a used range before calling getUsedRange